# Oracle Error ORA-00942 when updating Materialized View after some time (days, months)

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have a Materialized View that depends on other Materialized Views and Tables. After creating the Materialized View everything seems fine at first and I can update it using the following statement:

```
BEGIN DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH(LIST=>'v_my_materialized_view', atomic_refresh => false); END;
```

However, after some time (somtimes just a day, sometimes several months) I get the following error when executing the statement:

```
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2809
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 3025
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2994
ORA-06512: at line 1
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
```

What could be the reason for this? Is it a bug in Oracle?
I'm on Oracle 11.2.0.4.0, in case this is relevant.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that Oracle is wrong. More likely the table or view it is looking for does not exist - or cannot be accessed. You need to post more information.

Comment: A SELECT on the Materialized View is working, so I assume it exists. The permissions of the Materialized View or the elements used in it didn't change since it was created. Are there any reasons that could lead to it not being accessible anymore either way?